# BIML RootNode stays empty with named server

Tags: ssis-2012, biml

I am stunned by a problem in a very simple piece of code: the RootNode only contains 1 connection like this (i removed sensitive data):

```
<OleDbConnection Name="Source"   ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=Server\ServerName;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
```

When I write the compiled BIML to an XML file it contains this exact connection node. 
However when I use RootNode.Connections["Source"].GetDatabaseSchema it produces an error:

> Error 0 : BimlScript code produced an exception: Supplied connections must be of type AstDbConnectionNode for this method.

I think the compiler does not recognize my connection as a DBConnection.
I am using 2 BIML files one for connection and one for the import.

What I tried:
- verify that the connection works and I have access (using SSIS)
- put everything into one file
- try to find out if the backslash in the named server can be the problem. It looks like it can't be the problem because the backslash is no special character in XML.

Any ideas on this error, or how I can find out more?

Thanks,

Johan

Comment: Are you attempting to use two files (one for connection and one for the import) or all in one?

Comment: I updated my question to answer yours: I use 2 files but also tried to put everything into one file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing RootNode.Connections["Source"].GetDatabaseSchema to RootNode.OleDbConnections["Source"].GetDatabaseSchema() ?  RootNode.Connections is a list of all connections regardless of type.